# How do you go from a sum over frequencies to an integral?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I am trying to figure out how to go, with help of a density of states function $g(\omega)$, from a sum like this 
$$K=\sum \limits_{j=0}^N f(\omega_j)$$
to an integral over the frequencies for $N \to \infty$. The frequencies are eigenfrequencies of N harmonic oscillators coupled to a particle in a "harmonic oscillator bath".

But i think this is beside the point. I know the frequencies will not be evenly distributed because the oscillators may have different couplings, this is why I need the DOS, so that in the limit of $N \to \infty$ i can take evenly spaced frequencies $\omega_k$ and then 
$$\lim \limits_{N \to \infty} K=\lim \limits_{N \to \infty} \sum \limits_{k=0}^N g(\omega_k) f(\omega_k)$$.

What i am struggling with is getting the $d \omega$ basically. How do i get it from here? 
Does it somehow come from $\int \limits_0^{\infty} d \omega \; g(\omega)=N$(or is this wrong)? I  would need something like $\omega_k - \omega_{k+1} \over N$ but how would i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a string of irregularly placed (that is, not evenly spaced) christmas lights, and you want to calculate the total power emitted by all of them. There are two ways you can do this. One way is to sum over all lights the power emitted by a light. Another way would be divide the string of lights into segments of length $\Delta x$, and then sum the power emmitted by each segment over all the segments.

Mathematically, it is easy to write down the expression you get by calculating the total power $P$ the first way. If the position of the $i$th light bulb is $x_i$, and the power of the $i$th light bulb is $f(x_i)$, then the total power is simply given by $$P=\sum_i f(x_i).$$

Now let's try to think about how to do it the second way. What is the power emitted by the $n$th segment, which goes form $x=n\Delta x$ to $x=(n+1)\Delta x$? Answer: the power should be the average power emitted by lights on the segment times the number of lights on that segment. If $f(x)$ is the power of a light at position $x$, and this $f(x)$ varies smoothly, then the average power of a light on the segment we are considering is approximately $f(n\Delta x)$ (because $f$ is roughly constant over our small interval, so we just approximate $f(x)=f(n\Delta x)$). In addition to finding the average power, we also needed the number of lights in the interval. If $g(x)$ is the density of lights (that is, the number of lights per unit length at the position $x$), then the number of lights in our interval is $g(n\Delta x)\Delta x$ (assuming $g$ varies smoothly).

Putting the expression for the average power and the number of lights together, we get that the power $P_n$ emitted by our $n$th segment is 
\begin{equation}
P_n=\underbrace{f(n\Delta x)}_{\textrm{average power}}\,\cdot\, \underbrace{g(n\Delta x)\Delta x}_{\textrm{number of lights}}.
\end{equation}

Thus we get that the total power is

$$P=\sum_n P_n = \sum_n f(n\Delta x) g(n\Delta x)\Delta x.$$

Now remember above we had to make approximations which assumed that $f$ and $g$ were smooth. These approximations become exact in the limit $\Delta x \to 0$. Thus we obtain

$$P= \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sum_n f(n\Delta x) g(n\Delta x)\Delta x = \int f(x) g(x) dx.$$

This concludes the discussion of the christmas light problem. Now the problem you have is like the christmas light problem, except instead of christmas lights, you have states. And instead of being irregularly spaced in position, they are irregularly spaced in frequency, so $x \to \omega$. Also the quantity you are trying to compute is called $K$ instead of $P$. Thus we get

$$K=\int f(\omega) g(\omega) d\omega.$$

Comment: But how can this work? I mean $\sum_{i=0}^\infty f(\omega_i) \approx \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( g(\omega) \Delta \omega \right) f(n\Delta \omega)$ are not even the same units, are they? Since g has no units and $\Delta \omega$ should have units of a frequency? Shouldn't there be atleast some factor to cancel that? And how do you define $\Delta \omega$?

Comment: Okay i think i got it now. You of course have a density of states, implying that $g$ has the unit time. I would have wished for someone to give an exhaustive definition of DOS and addressing this as a special case, but i guess you can't always get what you want...^^ thanks anyway.

Comment: I would still like to know how you would definie $\Delta \omega$ here and why you have $g(\omega)$ in the second equation is this a mistake and should it maybe be $n \Delta \omega$?

Comment: Ok I rewrote my whole answer (v1 $\to$ v2). I think it is an improvement. You were right about the $g(\omega)$ mistake in the second equation. Hopefully the meaning of $\Delta \omega$ is clear from the second version. Basically, it is the length of a segment you are averaging over.